# Lazy dictionary properties in C#

Tags: c#, properties, lazy-initialization

I have a class with a property that's a Dictionary:

```
public class Entity 
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Name { get; set; }
}
```

I would like switch this property to use lazy initializtion. I tried the following:

```
public class Entity 
{
    private Lazy<Dictionary<string, string>> name = new Lazy<Dictionary<string, string>>(() => new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    public Dictionary<string, string> Name
    {
        get => name;
        set => name = value;
    }
}
```

This is of course an error, as Name and name have different types. For the life of me though, I can't figure out how to specify this correctly. All I really want is to have Name remain null until I access it, then create it on the first read or write.

Comment: [Realizing this question is 8 years old] Is ["_Using Lazy and ConcurrentDictionary to ensure a thread-safe, run-once, lazy-loaded collection_"](https://endjin.com/blog/2015/10/using-lazy-and-concurrentdictionary-to-ensure-a-thread-safe-run-once-lazy-loaded-collection) similar to what you were after?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the initialization with `Lazy`, but what you want is pretty simple and you could simply do this

```
private Dictionary<string, string> _name;
public Dictionary<string, string> Name
{
    get
    {
        if (_name == null)
            _name = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        return _name;
    }
    set _name = value;
}
```

EDIT: Note that this approach will have some thread safety issues. Check if this can be a problem for you.

Comment: You have a race condition in there.

Comment: Yeah added I added a note about this probably as you were typing your comment. ;)

Comment: D'oh, looks like I was using my [complicator's gloves](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The_Complicator_0x27_s_Gloves.aspx). This is what happens when I become enamored with a cool feature. Thanks, I'll mark this as the answer as soon SO lets me. Now, because I have a bunch of these, I just need to make some sort of factory for them.

Comment: or just `get { return _name ?? (_name = new Dictionary<string, string>()); }`

Comment: Yeah that's a nice one liner but some people won't like to assign in the return. I guess you lose some readability.

Comment: Or in C# early versions `get => _name ??= new();`

Answer (score 10):

`name.Value` is read-only. Try this:

```
public class Entity 
{
    private Lazy<Dictionary<string, string>> name = 
        new Lazy<Dictionary<string, string>>(
            () => new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    
    public Dictionary<string, string> Name => name.Value;
}
```